# cssSelector validation for controls withing iframe

Tags: iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

My sample page source is written below.

I am not able to access the elements (for example div id="company") those are withing iframe even i switched to iframe.

Generally i use to validate the cssSelector in chrome console before use in actual selenium code but in this case i can't. Elements above the ifreame are accessible.

```
'<div id="MainContent_TabContainer1_tp1_TabContainer2_TabPanel3" class="ajax__tab_panel"     style="visibility: visible;">
<iframe id="MainContent_TabContainer1_tp1_TabContainer2_TabPanel3_frame1" name="9432 JP"  frameborder="0" height="950px" width="1300" src="report.aspx? report=summary&amp;tic=9432+JP&amp;numcomps=5&amp;regions=United States"></iframe>
#document
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<head>
<body style="font-family: Calibri;">
<div id="all">
<div class="fixed" id="fixed">
<div id="company" class="company">NIPPON TELEGRAPH &amp; TELEPHONE - 9432 JP</div>
<div id="title" class="title">Telecommunication 
Services</div>'
```

Comment: What is the questions here? How is this tied in any way to Selenium or Selenium WebDriver? OP didn't mention either one at all in his post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have switched the control to frame before you can access any element inside iframe. But i think this is your issue.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("put IFrame ID or Name here");
```

Comment: I have switched to iframe before access the controls under iframe.

Comment: I have switched to iframe before access the controls under iframe. But when i try to access control under iframe, it displays me error that cannot locate this element. I also tried to access some of the controls under iframe in crome console but can not validate cssSelector for controls under iframe. Written cssSelector to access first div is $$("iframe[id='MainContent_TabContainer1_tp1_TabContainer2_TabPanel3_frame1']>div:nth-of-type(1)")

Comment: Can you please update your actual post with the code. I want to see how you coded you. Please show the iframe code and then how you tried to access the element.